# Rocketchat Docker Require custom modules

Tags: javascript, docker, rocket.chat

I am running rocketchat in a docker image and have set up a custom script which is executed when logged in. 
In this start script I want to import a module from another script, but when I start the container Meteor says

`Exception in template helper: Error: Cannot find module './helper/userHelper'`

in the web console

login.js

```
const userHelper = require('./helper/userHelper')

const user = { username: userHelper.getUsername(), email: userHelper.getEmail(), hashedPassword: userHelper.getHashedPassword() }
```

helper/userHelper.js

```
var cookie = getCookie()


function getCookie() {
    ....
    return cookie
}

function getUsername() {
    return cookie.userEmail.replace(/^(.*)@.*$/, '$1')
}

function getEmail() {
    return cookie.userEmail
}

function getHashedPassword() {
    return hash(email.split('').reverse().join(''))
}



function hash(s) {
    ....
    return hash
}




module.exports = { getCookie, getUsername, getEmail, getHashedPassword }
```

Comment: Please post the script involved and any relevant configuration

Comment: also add "docker" as a tag so relevant experts can check this

Comment: Please add a snipet from your Dockerfile.